# Where can I find information on what resources are consumed when connections are established with MSSQL 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to troubleshoot the following intermittent sql connection error:

> *"DESCRIPTION:    SQL Server failed with error code 0xc0000000 to spawn a thread to process a new login or connection. Check the SQL Server error log and the Windows event logs for information about possible related problems."*

This results in sql jobs failing, and our application getting the following exception:

> *“A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake”*

A Jonathan Kehayias post to MSDN in 2011 indicates the problem is worker thread starvation and that I need to scale out with additional servers. We're using SQL Server 2012 Enterprise (version 11.0.5058.0) with a 4-processor, 64-bit server, with 64GB of RAM and max worker threads set to 512. As I type this we are under significant load and sys.dm_os_workers only shows 218 threads. There is a 2ms Threadpool signal waits, and the average Threadpool wait time is 5ms. There are also no errors in any of the SQL logs other than what I listed. Also, anecdotally speaking, the error is very sporadic, and it tends to happen more in the off hours when server load is relatively low. Because of this I'm not 100% convinced there is a worker thread starvation problem.

Instead I'm beginning to think there is a race condition that briefly exhausts resources needed to create a connection. In addition to our main application connecting to the database (via ADO), I have several monitoring and maintenance jobs running at regular intervals (some as short as 1 minute).  I learned from our developers that the defaults are used for connection pooling. There is nothing in the connection strings that regulate pool size or connection duration. It seems reasonable that when the connection pool needs to grow, and jobs are connecting to the database that either SQL or Windows resources become scarce, for lack of a better term, which results in the errors I listed.

I’m looking for any resources that go into detail on what happens when an attempt is made to establish a connection with SQL Server.  All I really know is that establishing a connection is expensive, which is why connection pooling is recommended. I’m actually kind of lost at the moment, and thought getting a better understanding of how sql connections are made would help me troubleshoot this error faster, but I haven’t been able to find much with Google.

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: The reason for these errors was because there was not enough memory available to the OS.  I changed SQL Server's max memory setting to ensure the OS has at least 10% available memory and the error stopped occurring.  Here is the reddit discussion from r/SQLServer: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/SQLServer/comments/4o93zx/where_can_i_find_information_on_how_and_what/